# SignalR owin startup doesn't get hit. get "Object doesn't support property or method " javascript error

Tags: javascript, jquery, signalr, signalr-hub, owin

For the last many hours, I've been banging my head to make this work. I have a chat application using SignalR but am getting the javascript error "Object doesn't support property or method " while running it. I am using IIS to host the site.
I am guessing the javascript error is because the startup is not getting fired.

Please help.

[image]

after some time I found that owin startup is not getting hit.

```
    [assembly: OwinStartup( typeof( SignalrSimpleChat.Startup ) )]
    namespace SignalrSimpleChat

{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration( IAppBuilder app )
        {
            app.MapSignalR( ); // not getting hit!!!!
        }

    }
}
```

my nugget installs are

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="jQuery" version="2.0.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="json2" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="2.1.0-rc1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="2.1.0-rc1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="2.1.0-rc1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="5.0.8" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

here is my page

```
    <head>
    <title>Index</title>

    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/json2.js"></script>
   <script src="@Url.Content("~/signalr/hubs")"></script> 

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="text" disabled id="userName" />
        <input type="text" disabled id="groupName" />

        <input type="text" id="msg" />
        <input type="button" id="broadcast" value="broadcast" />
        <input type="button" id="groupcast" value="groupcast" />
        <ul id="messages">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            var chat = $.connection.chat;

            $('#userName').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
            $('#groupName').val(prompt('Enter your groupName:', ''));

            chat.userName = $('#userName').val();
            chat.groupName = $('#groupName').val();

            chat.addMessage = function (userName, groupName, message) {
                $('#messages').append('<li><b>' + groupName + "." + userName + ":</b>" + message + '</li>');
                $('#msg').val('');
            };

            $("#broadcast").click(function () {
                chat.sendAll(chat.userName, chat.groupName, $('#msg').val());
            });

            $("#groupcast").click(function () {
                chat.sendGroup(chat.userName, chat.groupName, $('#msg').val());
            });

            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                chat.join(chat.groupName);     //throws exception!!!!!!!!!
            });

            $.connection.hub.start();  

        });
```

and my code behind

```
namespace SignalrSimpleChat.Models.Helpers
{
    public class Chat : Hub
    {
        public void SendAll( string userName, string groupName, string message )
        {
            Clients.All.addMessage( userName, groupName, message );
        }

        public void SendGroup( string userName, string groupName, string message )
        {
            Clients.Group( groupName ).addMessage( userName, groupName, message );
        }

        public void Join( string groupName )
        {
            Groups.Add( Context.ConnectionId, groupName );
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: So you put a breakpoint inside `Configuration()` and it's not being hit? Is the breakpoint solid (not hollow)?

Comment: you are correct @SpikeX. it doesn't get hit under IIS but gets hit under VS serer.

Comment: so what was the configuration change to get MapSignalR() function to be hit?  Is there code that needs to run in the global.cs ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting in SignalR 1.0, client and server methods can only be accessed through the client and server namespaces respectively. State also got it's own namespace.

This change was made to avoid collisions between client and server methods. Your JS code would change to look like this:

```
    $(function () {

        var chat = $.connection.chat;

        $('#userName').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
        $('#groupName').val(prompt('Enter your groupName:', ''));

        chat.state.userName = $('#userName').val();
        chat.state.groupName = $('#groupName').val();

        chat.client.addMessage = function (userName, groupName, message) {
            $('#messages').append('<li><b>' + groupName + "." + userName + ":</b>" + message + '</li>');
            $('#msg').val('');
        };

        $("#broadcast").click(function () {
            chat.server.sendAll(chat.userName, chat.groupName, $('#msg').val());
        });

        $("#groupcast").click(function () {
            chat.server.sendGroup(chat.userName, chat.groupName, $('#msg').val());
        });

        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            chat.server.join(chat.groupName);     //should no longer throw exception!!!!!!!!!
        });

        $.connection.hub.start();  

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    chat.server.join('test');
});
```

If doesnt work, try without local variable:

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    $.connection.chat.server.join('test');
});
```

Some resources:
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20

Comment: if you look at my page code, your suggestion is already there. I think the problem is that my owin startup is not firing.???

Comment: apparently the issue was something else. we luckily got an answer below that should also help other people.